# Trying to create List in Marketing cloud Via SOAP API response is OK but Not reflecting in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, installedpackage

I am trying to create a list in marketing cloud through SOAP API .
Have followed the documentation.getting the response as OK but the list is not getting created in Marketing cloud.

Using SOAPUI:for soap api Testing.
Installed packages: Server-to-Server

it will be very helpful if some information on above question and find where it is going wrong.

Comment: You need to provide the call you are using

Answer (score -1):

Some API features need to be enabled by Salesforce Support. 
F.e. Async Insert is something that needs to be enabled on your account before you can use it.
This will also give you a 202 response but won't perform any actions.

But, as commenter said, you should share your payload and method to make sure there are no errors in what you are doing.